# How do you get LazyColumns to share available space without pushing off the screen?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to figure out how to get a layout that behaves like a combo of `ColumnSpec.weight` and "wrap_content".  By that I mean, I want it to behave as "wrap_content" if it can fit within the bounds of the available space, but as a weighted distribution if it cannot.

The layout I'm trying to create is basically this (this is my "testing" ui):

```
            Box(modifier = Modifier.size(800.dp, 300.dp)) {

                Column(modifier=Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                    Text("HEADER")
                    LazyColumn {
                        items(15) {
                            Text("item", modifier=Modifier.padding(start=20.dp))
                        }
                    }

                    Text("HEADER")
                    LazyColumn {
                        items(3) {
                            Text("item", modifier=Modifier.padding(start=20.dp))
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
```

It's 2 (or more) lists with headers.  The problem is, if I use default layout options, when the first list becomes too long it completely pushes the second list off the screen.

The behavior I want is:

1. if both lists are short enough to be on screen, display both, with vertical alignment of top (the default behavior).
2. if one list is too long, the shorter list takes up the space it needs and the longer list takes up remaining space and scrolls.
3. if both lists are long, the space is split evenly between them and they both scroll

I've tried using a `ConstraintLayout`, but like the default layouts it gets pushed off the screen.

I've tried using `ColumnSpec.weight`, which *does* keep everything on screen, but distributes space evenly, so a short list will take up more room than it needs and display blank space:

[image]

Using the parameter `fill=false` *almost* gets me there, but "non-filled" space in the second list is not used by the first list, so there is blank space even though the first list is truncated (first list has 15 items and should expand to take up available space).

[image]

Is what I'm trying to accomplish possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, I don't think you can do it with any traditional Layout.

**Update: It works properly now**

Fixed all issues and added a few comments, should be fairly easy to tweak it if you wish.

Use `Modifier.wrapOrFit()` to indicate which layouts you want to distribute space to.

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.rememberScrollState
import androidx.compose.foundation.verticalScroll
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.Layout
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.Measurable
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.ParentDataModifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.Constraints
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.Density
import kotlin.math.roundToInt

@Preview
@Composable
fun Foo0() {
    FitAllLayout(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Text("All Elements Fit")
        Text("Header 1")
        Column(
            Modifier
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                .wrapOrFit()) {
            repeat(4) {
                Text("Hello $it")
            }
        }
        Text("Header 2")
        Column(
            Modifier
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                .wrapOrFit()) {
            repeat(4) {
                Text("World $it")
            }
        }
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun Foo1() {
    FitAllLayout(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Text("First List Fits, Second Becomes Scrollable")
        Text("Header 1")
        Column(
            Modifier
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                .wrapOrFit()) {
            repeat(4) {
                Text("Hello $it")
            }
        }
        Text("Header 2")
        Column(
            Modifier
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                .wrapOrFit()) {
            repeat(50) {
                Text("World $it")
            }
        }
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun Foo2() {
    FitAllLayout(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Text("First list expands enough so that second list fits completely")
        Text("Header 1")
        Column(
            Modifier
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                .wrapOrFit()) {
            repeat(50) {
                Text("Hello $it")
            }
        }
        Text("Header 2")
        Column(
            Modifier
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                .wrapOrFit()) {
            repeat(4) {
                Text("World $it")
            }
        }
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun Foo3() {
    FitAllLayout(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Text("First List fits completely, third list gains twice as much space than the second one due to having double the content")
        Text("Header 1")
        Column(
            Modifier
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                .wrapOrFit()) {
            repeat(4) {
                Text("Hello $it")
            }
        }
        Text("Header 2")
        Column(
            Modifier
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                .wrapOrFit()) {
            repeat(25) {
                Text("FooBar $it")
            }
        }
        Text("Header 3")
        Column(
            Modifier
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                .wrapOrFit()) {
            repeat(50) {
                Text("World $it")
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun FitAllLayout(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: @Composable FitAllLayoutScope.() -> Unit
) {
    Layout(
        modifier = modifier,
        measurePolicy = { measurables, constraints ->
            val placeables = if (constraints.hasBoundedHeight) {
                val measureFirst = mutableListOf<Measurable>()
                val measureLast = mutableListOf<Measurable>()

                measurables.forEach { measurable ->
                    // Separate measurables that we want to distribute space to by the presence of
                    // the `WrapOrFit` object
                    val wrapOrFit = (measurable.parentData as? WrapOrFit) != null
                    if (wrapOrFit) {
                        measureLast.add(measurable)
                    } else {
                        measureFirst.add(measurable)
                    }
                }
                val remainingHeight =
                    constraints.maxHeight - measureFirst.fold(0) { acc, measurable ->
                        acc + measurable.minIntrinsicHeight(constraints.maxWidth)
                    }
                var requiredHeight = 0
                val measurableToMinHeight = mutableMapOf<Measurable, Int>()
                var minSharedHeight =
                    Constraints.Infinity // We need the minimum height between all lists
                measureLast.forEach {
                    val minHeight = it.minIntrinsicHeight(constraints.maxWidth)
                    minSharedHeight = minOf(minSharedHeight, minHeight)
                    requiredHeight += minHeight
                    measurableToMinHeight[it] = minHeight
                }
                if (requiredHeight <= remainingHeight) {
                    // All Items Fit
                    measurables.map {
                        it.measure(
                            Constraints(
                                minWidth = 0,
                                maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth,
                                minHeight = 0,
                                maxHeight = constraints.maxHeight
                            )
                        )
                    }
                } else {
                    val distributableHeight = remainingHeight - (minSharedHeight * measureLast.size)
                    if (distributableHeight > 0) {
                        // All items fit to a common minimum height, there's enough space to
                        // redistribute based on their original height
                        val maxConstraints = mutableMapOf<Measurable, Int>()

                        // Space to use to calculate weights
                        var totalRemainder = 0
                        val remainderForWeight = measurableToMinHeight.map {
                            // Total space is calculated as the sum of the space that each list
                            // exceeds the height of the smallest item
                            val diff = it.value - minSharedHeight
                            totalRemainder += diff
                            Pair(it.key, diff)
                        }.toMap()

                        // Calculate maximum of each list, so that the longest list gets the most
                        // space and the smallest remains on the same height
                        measureLast.forEach {
                            val weight =
                                1f * remainderForWeight.getOrDefault(it, 0) / totalRemainder
                            maxConstraints[it] =
                                minSharedHeight + (distributableHeight * weight).roundToInt()
                        }
                        measurables.map {
                            if (maxConstraints.containsKey(it)) {
                                it.measure(
                                    Constraints(
                                        minWidth = 0,
                                        maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth,
                                        minHeight = minSharedHeight,
                                        maxHeight = maxConstraints[it]!!
                                    )
                                )
                            } else {
                                it.measure(
                                    Constraints(
                                        minWidth = 0,
                                        maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth,
                                        minHeight = 0,
                                        maxHeight = Constraints.Infinity
                                    )
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        // No space to distribute, layout lists evenly.
                        // Alternatively a similar logic could be used as above, but there's a risk
                        // of a list ending up being too small to display its contents
                        val maxHeight = (1f * remainingHeight / measureLast.size).roundToInt()
                        measurables.map {
                            if (measurableToMinHeight.containsKey(it)) {
                                // Lists measured up to a common maximum height
                                it.measure(
                                    Constraints(
                                        minWidth = 0,
                                        maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth,
                                        minHeight = 0,
                                        maxHeight = maxHeight
                                    )
                                )
                            } else {
                                // All other elements will be measure at wrap content
                                it.measure(
                                    Constraints(
                                        minWidth = 0,
                                        maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth,
                                        minHeight = 0,
                                        maxHeight = Constraints.Infinity
                                    )
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                measurables.map {
                    it.measure(constraints)
                }
            }

            var maxHeight = 0
            var maxWidth = 0
            placeables.forEach {
                maxHeight += it.height
                maxWidth = maxOf(maxWidth, it.width)
            }

            val layoutWidth = when {
                constraints.hasFixedWidth -> constraints.minWidth
                constraints.hasBoundedWidth -> maxOf(
                    minOf(maxWidth, constraints.maxWidth),
                    constraints.minWidth
                )

                else -> maxOf(maxWidth, constraints.minWidth)
            }
            val layoutHeight = when {
                constraints.hasFixedHeight -> constraints.minHeight
                constraints.hasBoundedHeight -> maxOf(
                    minOf(maxHeight, constraints.maxHeight),
                    constraints.minHeight
                )

                else -> maxOf(maxHeight, constraints.minHeight)
            }

            layout(layoutWidth, layoutHeight) {
                var currY = 0
                placeables.forEach { placeable ->
                    placeable.place(0, currY)
                    currY += placeable.height
                }
            }
        },
        content = {
            FitAllLayoutScope.content()
        }
    )
}

object FitAllLayoutScope {
    fun Modifier.wrapOrFit(): Modifier =
        this.then(WrapOrFitModifier())
}

private class WrapOrFitModifier : ParentDataModifier {
    override fun Density.modifyParentData(parentData: Any?): Any {
        return WrapOrFit
    }
}

private object WrapOrFit
```

Here's the result:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v05E1.png)

**Original Reply:**

Here's a poor attempt, tho it's a good start if you don't mind dealing with custom layouts.

Keep in mind the following:

- The math is off
- Not sure why there are gaps sometimes
- Not sure why it tries to center everything
- It breaks apart with three elements (the weight is not distributed properly, see Foo2)

Use Modifier.wrapOrFit() to indicate which layouts you want to distribute space to.

Sorry for the lack of comments, this was more exhausting than I thought it would be.

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.rememberScrollState
import androidx.compose.foundation.verticalScroll
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.Layout
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.Measurable
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.MeasurePolicy
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.ParentDataModifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.Constraints
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.Density
import kotlin.math.roundToInt

@Preview
@Composable
fun Foo0() {
    FitAllLayout(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Text("Header 1")
        Column(Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()).wrapOrFit()) {
            repeat(4) {
                Text("Hello $it")
            }
        }
        Text("Header 2")
        Column(Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()).wrapOrFit()) {
            repeat(4) {
                Text("World $it")
            }
        }
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun Foo1() {
    FitAllLayout(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Text("Header 1")
        Column(Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()).wrapOrFit()) {
            repeat(4) {
                Text("Hello $it")
            }
        }
        Text("Header 2")
        Column(Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()).wrapOrFit()) {
            repeat(50) {
                Text("World $it")
            }
        }
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun Foo2() {
    FitAllLayout(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        Text("Header 1")
        Column(Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()).wrapOrFit()) {
            repeat(4) {
                Text("Hello $it")
            }
        }
        Text("Header 3")
        Column(Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()).wrapOrFit()) {
            repeat(20) {
                Text("FooBar $it")
            }
        }
        Text("Header 3")
        Column(Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()).wrapOrFit()) {
            repeat(50) {
                Text("World $it")
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun FitAllLayout(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    content: @Composable FitAllLayoutScope.() -> Unit
) {
    Layout(
        modifier = modifier,
        measurePolicy = MeasurePolicy { measurables, constraints ->
            val placeables = if (constraints.hasBoundedHeight) {
                val measureFirst = mutableListOf<Measurable>()
                val measureLast = mutableListOf<Measurable>()
                measurables.forEach { measurable ->
                    val wrapOrFit = (measurable.parentData as? WrapOrFit) != null
                    if (wrapOrFit) {
                        measureLast.add(measurable)
                    } else {
                        measureFirst.add(measurable)
                    }
                }
                val remainingHeight =
                    constraints.maxHeight - measureFirst.fold(0) { acc, measurable ->
                        acc + measurable.minIntrinsicHeight(constraints.maxWidth)
                    }
                var requiredHeight = 0
                val measurableToMinHeight = mutableMapOf<Measurable, Int>()
                var minSharedHeight = Constraints.Infinity
                measureLast.sortBy {
                    val minHeight = it.minIntrinsicHeight(constraints.maxWidth)
                    minSharedHeight = minOf(minSharedHeight, minHeight)
                    requiredHeight += minHeight
                    measurableToMinHeight[it] = minHeight
                    minHeight
                }
                if (requiredHeight <= remainingHeight) {
                    measurables.map {
                        it.measure(
                            Constraints(
                                minWidth = 0,
                                maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth,
                                minHeight = 0,
                                maxHeight = constraints.maxHeight
                            )
                        )
                    }
                } else {
                    val distributableHeight = remainingHeight - (minSharedHeight * measureLast.size)
                    if (distributableHeight > 0) {
                        val totalHeight = requiredHeight - minSharedHeight
                        val maxConstraints = mutableMapOf<Measurable, Int>()
                        measureLast.forEach {
                            if (measurableToMinHeight[it] != minSharedHeight) {
                                val weight = 1f * totalHeight / measurableToMinHeight[it]!!
                                maxConstraints[it] = (distributableHeight * weight).roundToInt()
                            } else {
                                maxConstraints[it] = minSharedHeight
                            }
                        }
                        measurables.map {
                            if (maxConstraints.containsKey(it)) {
                                it.measure(
                                    Constraints(
                                        minWidth = 0,
                                        maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth,
                                        minHeight = minSharedHeight,
                                        maxHeight = maxConstraints[it]!!
                                    )
                                )
                            } else {
                                it.measure(
                                    Constraints(
                                        minWidth = 0,
                                        maxWidth = Constraints.Infinity,
                                        minHeight = 0,
                                        maxHeight = Constraints.Infinity
                                    )
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        // distribute evenly
                        val maxHeight = (1f * remainingHeight / measureLast.size).roundToInt()
                        measurables.map {
                            if (measurableToMinHeight.containsKey(it)) {
                                it.measure(
                                    Constraints(
                                        minWidth = 0,
                                        maxWidth = constraints.maxWidth,
                                        minHeight = 0,
                                        maxHeight = maxHeight
                                    )
                                )
                            } else {
                                it.measure(
                                    Constraints(
                                        minWidth = 0,
                                        maxWidth = Constraints.Infinity,
                                        minHeight = 0,
                                        maxHeight = Constraints.Infinity
                                    )
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                measurables.map {
                    it.measure(constraints)
                }
            }

            var maxHeight = 0
            var maxWidth = 0
            placeables.forEach {
                maxHeight += it.height
                maxWidth = maxOf(maxWidth, it.width)
            }

            layout(maxWidth, minOf(maxHeight, constraints.maxHeight)) {
                var currY = 0
                placeables.forEach { placeable ->
                    placeable.place(0, currY)
                    currY += placeable.height
                }
            }
        },
        content = {
            FitAllLayoutScope().content()
        }
    )
}

class FitAllLayoutScope {
    fun Modifier.wrapOrFit(): Modifier =
        this.then(WrapOrFitModifier())
}

class WrapOrFitModifier : ParentDataModifier {
    override fun Density.modifyParentData(parentData: Any?): Any? {
        return WrapOrFit
    }
}

object WrapOrFit
```

Comment: wow, that's neat that you figured it out, and crazy that it's so complicated to pull off.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of how to do it with any traditional layout but
It might be possible to set the weights in the constraints in ConstraintLayout or you might want to write your own layout.

This is as close as I could come with ConstraintLayout:

```kotlin
@Preview
@Composable
fun foo() {
    ConstraintLayout(modifier = Modifier
        .size(800.dp, 300.dp)
        .background(Color.White)) {
        val (h1, h2, lc1, lc2) = createRefs()
        createVerticalChain(
            h1,
            lc1.withChainParams(weight = 1f),
            h2,
            lc2.withChainParams(weight = 1f),
            chainStyle = ChainStyle.Packed(0f)
        )

        Text("HEADER", modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(h1) {
            width = Dimension.matchParent
            height = Dimension.wrapContent
        })
        LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(lc1) {
            width = Dimension.matchParent
            height = Dimension.preferredWrapContent
        }) {
            items(11) {
                Text("item", modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 20.dp))
            }
        }

        Text("HEADER", modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(h2) {
            width = Dimension.matchParent
            height = Dimension.wrapContent
        })
        LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(lc2) {
            width = Dimension.matchParent
            height = Dimension.preferredWrapContent
        }) {
            items(2) {
                Text("item", modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 20.dp))
            }
        }
    }

}
```